# Why is my image vertically centred when using a stylesheet and at the top of the div when using inline styling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When using inline styling, the image in my nav bar is placed at the top of it's parent div. However, when I apply the same styling using a stylesheet, the image is centred in the nav bar.

**Inline:**

***HTML:***

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row" style = "height: 100vh">

        <div class = "col-3" style =  "background-color: #242424">
            <img src = "/image" style = "height: auto; width: 100%">
        </div>

        <div class = "col-9" style = "background-color: #2A2A2A">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Screenshot:***
[image]

**Stylesheet:**

***HTML:***

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row" style = "height: 100vh">

        <div class = "col-3 navbar">
            <img src = "/image" style = "height: auto; width: 100%">
        </div>

        <div class = "col-9" style = "background-color: #2A2A2A">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #242424;
}
```

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Why is there a difference in image placement between these two styling definitions, which to my understanding do the exact same thing? If I were to use the stylesheet,

how would I have the image remain to be placed at the top of its parent div?

Comment: adding a background colour should have no affect on vertical alignment whether it is in a stylesheet or inline - there must be something else in your stylesheet causing it.  Although in the second example, you add the navbar class to the col - perhaps it's something in the styles for the navbar making the difference (I think that may be a reserved bootstrap class - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)